# calling js method from a link

Tags: javascript, html

in the head i have

```
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the body I have

```
<a href="remove_fields(this)">xremove</a>
```

in the js I have

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  ...
}
```

clicking xremove link i get

```
No route matches [GET] "/recipes/1/remove_fields(this)"
```

whats wrong ?

EDIT - Updated the question for simplicity

Comment: Any errors? Your `add_fields(this, , );` call isn't valid JavaScript. And is `add_fields` global? It needs to be for inline handlers.

Comment: Yes, why don't you type `add_fields(this, , );` into a Javascript console to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use inline JavaScript. It's all against the known best practises.

Use event handlers instead:

```
<a href="#" id="link">

<script>
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function() {
    // do whatever you want
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Most of the code was generated in rails. So I just wanted to know what should I fixed

Comment: What does "use event handlers instead" mean? An inline event attribute is just another way of assigning an event handler.

Comment: Sure it is. I was pointing to "seperation of concerns" philosophy: Write pure HTML (content), style it with CSS (design) and give it a life with JavaScript (behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Rails is generating an invalid Javascript call for your onclick. The function call has commas with no arguments which must mean that whatever data Rails is trying to put in for those arguments must be null.

Check your Rails templates to see what it is trying to stuff there.

UPDATE: Since you changed your question, here is a new answer:

You can't refer to javascript directly in the href. You have to append "javascript:" in front of your function call or else put it in the onclick handler.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the perfectly valid answer above, take advantage of the extreme simplification of the jQuery API by first including the Google CDN Hosted minified library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then just like above, (but jQuery-style), much simpler IMO:

```
<a href="#" id="link">

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#link").click(function (event)
{    
    // Handle event here. This code will be executed whenever event is triggered
    // ie. whenever you click the element with id link
});
```

I am a less experienced web programmer and don't have nearly as much knowledge about best practices in functional/interpretted languages like javascript as I do in native areas such as Assembly, C++, Java. But I can most certainly see why jQuery is so popular, even among the huge tech companies such as Microsoft and Google, when you compare just the writability/readability and of the answer given above and the jQuery version here. I will stick with this when I can.

Here is a link to the excellent [jQuery documentation on the .click() method](http://api.jquery.com/click/).